# How to drop database in H2?

Tags: h2, keycloak

I use the sql statement `DROP DATABASE KEYCLOAK;` This throws a syntax error in h2 console.

error

```
drop database keycloak;
Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP DATABASE[*] KEYCLOAK "; expected "TABLE, INDEX, USER, SEQUENCE, CONSTANT, TRIGGER, VIEW, ROLE, ALIAS, SCHEMA, ALL, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE"; SQL statement:
drop database keycloak [42001-193] 42001/42001 (Help)
```

There does not seem to be any error in syntax. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really need to drop the whole database in H2 Console, use

```sql
DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES;
SHUTDOWN;
```

You'll see “Database is already closed” error or something like it after execution of `SHUTDOWN` command, it should be ignored.

If you want to drop only your schema (in some other DBMS the “database” term is used for a schema, but in H2 they are different things), use

```sql
DROP SCHEMA schemaName;
```

where schemaName is a name of your schema.

Note: the `PUBLIC` schema cannot be dropped and there are no commands to clear all its content at once. But there is a command to drop all other objects in the database, it is the same

```sql
DROP ALL OBJECTS
```

command, but without `DELETE FILES` clause. It preserves only the current user, the `PUBLIC` role, and the empty `PUBLIC` schema (content of this schema is dropped).

All these commands are destructive and cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Use 'DROP SCHEMA schemaName CASCADE;' if you want to drop the schema with tables.

Comment: Also not: `DROP ALL OBJECTS DELETE FILES;` deletes the persistient database file created with the H2 `shell` tool.

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing an error because you are trying to drop database that doesn't exist. Try this following options.

Drop Table: Drop Table is a command that deletes the respective table and its structure.

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME;
```

Drop Schema:Drop Schema is a command that drops a respective schema from the database server. It will not work from the current schema.

```
DROP SCHEMA SCHEMA_NAME;
```

Comment: it exists also the it show a syntax error just after database[*] do not know why.

Comment: The error with code 42001 is thrown when trying to execute an invalid SQL statement